# Generic term for parser/serializer

Tags: terminology, programming

Decoding and encoding can be thought of as the same process, but in opposite directions. The generic word for a bidirectional encoder/decoder is [“codec”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec):

> a portmanteau of *coder-decoder*.

Parsing and serialization can also be thought of as the same process, but in opposite directions.

Is there an equivalent word to “codec”, but for the bidirectional process of parsing/serialization?

Comment: Since "parsing" = "decoding", and "serialization" = "encoding" (they're just different words for the same process, in this context), why can't you just continue to use the word ***codec*** for a "combined serializer / parser"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think they're the same. Encoding and decoding are `serialized A ↔ serialized B`, whereas parsing and serializing are `complex structure (usually tree) ↔ serialized`.

Comment: So far as I'm concerned, serialising/deserialising just means storing and retrieving data structures, which is essentially the same thing as encoding/decoding. But this is really domain-specific "jargon coinage" rather than the general use of English, so if you want to specifically focus on that "memory table to disc-based file and back again" conversion I guess maybe something like ***marshalling*** might do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Though not really a word, ***serde*** (*serialization* + *deserialization*) is composed in pretty much the same manner as *coder* + *decoder*.

Several libraries use this name:

- https://pypi.org/project/serde/
- https://serde.rs/
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SerDe

Comment: Awesome answer! But I disagree about “not really a word” — what is and isn't considered a word is purely down to consensus. If a few libraries have all converged on the same word, there’s already some (limited) consensus.